# bott element in periodic cyclic homology

Tags: homotopy-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, homology

I am reading a paper by Thomason "Algebraic K-theory and étale cohomology", which deals with algebraic K theory localized by inverting the bott element $\beta \in K_2(\overline{k})^{\wedge}_l$, where $\overline{k}$ is a closed field and $l$ is a prime not equal to the characteristic of $\overline{k}$.

While reading the paper, I have a few questions.

(1) When $\beta$ is viewed as the element $\beta\in \text{HC}_2(\overline{k}/\overline{k})^{\wedge}_l$ (resp. $\beta\in \text{HC}_2(\overline{k}/{k})^{\wedge}_l$) through the trace map $K(\overline{k})^{\wedge}_l \to \text{HC}(\overline{k}/\overline{k})^{\wedge}_l$ (resp. $K(\overline{k})^{\wedge}_l \to \beta\in \text{HC}_2(\overline{k}/{k})^{\wedge}_l$), what is $\text{HC}(\overline{k}/\overline{k})[\beta^{-1}]^{\wedge}_l$? (resp. $\text{HC}(\overline{k}/{k})[\beta^{-1}]^{\wedge}_l$)

(2) When $\beta$ is viewed as the element $\beta\in \text{HP}_2(\overline{k}/\overline{k})^{\wedge}_l$ (resp. $\beta\in \text{HP}_2(\overline{k}/{k})^{\wedge}_l$) through the trace map $K(\overline{k})^{\wedge}_l \to \text{HP}(\overline{k}/\overline{k})^{\wedge}_l$ (resp. $K(\overline{k})^{\wedge}_l \to \beta\in \text{HP}_2(\overline{k}/{k})^{\wedge}_l$), what is $\text{HP}(\overline{k}/\overline{k})[\beta^{-1}]^{\wedge}_l$? (resp. $\text{HP}(\overline{k}/{k})[\beta^{-1}]^{\wedge}_l$)

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. The target of the Dennis trace map seems to be the negative cyclic homology $\operatorname{HC}^-$?